# Fetch row with different data on same column

Tags: php, mysql, sql

We have the table structure like

```
Fieldid userid data
41       2      1
12       2      0
41       3      1
12       3      1
```

We want the user which have (data=1 and filedid = 41) and (data = 0 and filedid=12)

We tried the query

```
select userid from table 
where (data=1 and filedid = 41) 
AND (data = 0 and filedid=12)
```

but it returns empty results. 
Can anyone help how we will get the record using MySQL?

Comment: you should use `or` between the 2 conditions.. `(data=1 and filedid = 41) OR (data = 0 and filedid=12)`

Comment: but it returns if any one of the condition is true.

Comment: but the filed id is different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use grouping with a *conditional aggregate* in the `HAVING` clause:

```
SELECT userid
FROM mytable
GROUP BY userid
HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN data = 1 AND FieldId = 1 THEN 1 END) >= 1 AND
       COUNT(CASE WHEN data = 0 AND FieldId = 12 THEN 1 END) >= 1
```

Comment: Why? Why use `HAVING` when you can achieve same thing with simple `OR`/`AND`?

Comment: @ElonThan I think the OP wants to return *just* `userid=2`. In that case you have to use a conditional aggregate like the one of my query so as to test whether the *group* satisfies *both* conditions.

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos as stated in question, he wants something else. And you can clearly see that from query that he tried.

Comment: @ElonThan The OP states *We want the user which have (data=1 and filedid = 41) and (data = 0 and filedid=12)*, so his intention is to get `userid` values satisfying *both* predicates contained inside the parentheses.

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos Yes i wants to get  just userid=2.

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos Thanks for your help. it's working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to @Giorgos, with multicolumn compare for conciseness:

```
select userid
from t
group by userid
having  sum((data,fieldId) = (1, 41)) > 0
    and sum((data,fieldId) = (0, 12)) > 0
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to use `union all` like:

```
select * from table1 where Fieldid = 41 and data = 1 union all
select * from table1 where Fieldid = 12 and data = 0
```

attached image shows the output

[image]

Answer (score -1):

When searching for results with one or another set of data you have to use `OR` keyword, not `AND`.

```
SELECT userid FROM table 
WHERE (data = 1 AND filedid = 41) 
OR (data = 0 AND filedid = 12)
```

Comment: The OP is interested in userids which satisfy BOTH criteria.

Comment: @Strawberry he tried to fetch data using query like this so I'm pretty sure it's correct answer. Just check out his example query. What data is he using there?